# html javascript output and converter bugs

Tags: javascript, html

The converter is working fine, it looks for a match to the input and if it finds one, it converts it to the new value.

The problem I am running into is that I can output the new value with document.write(userInput);

But I dont know how to format or add html and text to the output.  Help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Value Converter</h1>

<input type="text" id="userInput"=>Enter the Value</input>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function test()
            {
   var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
   if(userInput == "xxxx") {
      userInput="yyyy";
   }
   else if(userInput == "yyyy") {
      userInput="zzzz";
   }
   else {
      userInput="Not Found";
   }
        document.write("<br /><br /><b> The equivalent value is: </b>") + (userInput) + ("< br /><br /><a href="/test.html"><b>Click here to Start Over</b></a>");      
        }

            // Need to fix the "reset" to go back to restart the program

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dont use document.write, use the DOM attributes like innerHTML,innerText etc That way you can just reuse the same page without having to have the user reload it.

Comment: What would be the code to use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.write("<br /><br /><b> The equivalent value is: </b>") + (userInput) + ("< br /><br /><a href="/test.html"><b>Click here to Start Over</b></a>");
```

For

```
document.write("<br /><br /><b> The equivalent value is: </b>" + userInput + "< br /><br /><a href="/test.html"><b>Click here to Start Over</b></a>");
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work.  The program stops firing and wont display anything when submit is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the html the way you want it to look, and then modify it using innerHTML or whatever DOM function/attributes instead of overwriting the page or having to reload it.

***HTML***

```
<h1>Value Converter</h1>
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter a value" />
<div>
   <span>The equivalent value is: </span>
   <span id="output">Enter a value and submit first</span>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

***JS***

```
function test() {
   var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
   var converted = "";
   switch(userInput){
      case "someXXX":
         //Do whatever code here 
         converted = "yyy";
      break;
      case "someYYY":
         //Do whatever code here
         converted = "zzz";
      break;
      default:
         //Do whatever when all else fails
         converted = "Not found";
      break;
   }        
   var output = document.getElementById("output");
   output.innerHTML = converted;
}
```

Note that I changed your if statements to a switch/case

[***JSFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/tUJ36/)